# Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: apache, virtualhost, ubuntu, lamp, localhost

I am getting a 403 when i access `http://mayfieldafc.local/` upon looking in the Apache logs I am getting:

```
[Wed Nov 16 12:32:59 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible: /var/www
```

I have what i believe to be the correct permissions set on /var/www. hutber can create and delete files, hutber being my user. I can also execute as program on this folder.

In mayfields vhost its:

```
<Directory /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot>

Options +FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Order allow,deny

    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

I am pulling my hair out not being able to work on my sites with my work Ubuntu install. I know of nothing else that could be effecting this.

So any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your error message references /var/www, not your documentroot.  So it would be a more broad  stanza that covers whether symlinks are allowed (in / or in /var)